# Como llamar métodos dentro de una función JQuery?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Me veo en la necesidad de llamar a una método el cual me retorne un valor, pero al estar dentro de una function en JQuery, el **this**, se convierte en un selector para acceder a los elementos y ya no lo puedo usar para llamar al método: ejemplo this.RetornarValor().

Este es el codigo con el que estoy trabajando y necesito llamar al metodo dentro del .each()

```
private Prueba() {
    // Obtengo la N cantidad de recetas
    let recetas = document.querySelectorAll('.receta');
    // Recorro cada receta
    recetas.forEach(receta => {
        let total = 0;
        let indice = this.ObtenerIndice(receta.id)
        let tabla = '#data-table-' + receta.id + ' tbody';
        console.log(tabla);
        // clases-options es la clase que le di a los selects
        $(tabla).find('.clases-options').each(function () {
            let $productoSelect = $(this),
                $tr = $productoSelect.closest('tr'),
                $tdClase = $tr.find('td.clase-prod'),
                value = $productoSelect.val().toString();
            // Este valor es el que quiero enviar por parámetro a un método
            $tdClase.text(value);
        })
    });
}
```

He probado (ingenuamente) con un cambiar el .find(function) por un .on('change', event =>{}) y aunque de de esa manera ya puedo acceder a los métodos, dejo de poder obtener los valores de los select y por así decirlo ya no puedo acceder a los elementos html como el  adyacente.

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver mi problema al asignar una variable a this, de esa manera poder seguir llamando a los demás métodos fuera de la función .each()

```
let metodos = this;
$(tabla).find('.clases-options').each(function () {
        let $productoSelect = $(this),
            $tr = $productoSelect.closest('tr'),
            $tdClase = $tr.find('td.clase-prod'),
            value = $productoSelect.val().toString();
        metodos.Extraer(value);
});
```

Comment: Sólo como nota, la convención general que se suele usar es el nombre `self`, para hacer referencia al contexto de la función padre, `const self = this`.